# Is importScripts() only for webworkers?

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

Can it be used as a means of including code from external .js files outside of the context of webworkers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is importScripts() only for webworkers?

Yes, this is a webworker-specific API, like `onmessage`. You can't use it outside of that context.

Comment: So outside of webworkers I need to stick to AJAX calls or <script> tags to import javascript code?

Comment: Yes - script tags, jQuery's getScript, or other loaders.